# React Application 'npm test' Warning

Tags: reactjs, testing

I created a React application for practice. It works in my browser; however when I ran "**npm test**" from my terminal, it giving me a warning "***Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component.  Please check the code for the FetchOne component.***"

I checked the FetchOne component but I couldn't figure it out. Is there anybody help me out, thank you!

Here is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
const API = 'https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=';
const DEFAULE_TITLE = 'N/A title';

class FetchOne extends Component{
  constructor(){
  super()
  this.state=({
  hits: [],
  isLoading: false,
  error: null,
 })
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.setState({ isLoading: true })
   fetch(API)
  .then(response =>{
   if(response.ok){
     return response.json()
    }else{
        throw Error('Somethig went wrong...')
         }
     } )
  .then( data => this.setState({
      hits: data.hits,
      isLoading: false,
  }))
  .catch(error => this.setState({
       error,
       isLoading: false
      }))
  }

 render(){
  const { hits, isLoading, error } = this.state;
    if(isLoading){
      return <p> Loading... </p>
     }
    if(error){
      return <p>{error.message}</p>
     }

 return(
   <div>
    {hits.map(data =>
      <ul key={data.objectID}>
          <li>Title:<a href={data.url}> {data.title || DEFAULE_TITLE}</a></li>
          <li>Author: {data.author}</li>
          <li>Points: {data.points}</li>
      </ul>
    )}
   </div>
   )
  }
 }
export default FetchOne
```

[Click HERE for Error Massage Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sDnD.png)

Comment: how does your test look like?

Comment: I added a Link of the test result at the end of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue previously. The issue related to the fact that the component had unmounted but I was still making a `setState` call. This can happen when using async functions and passing a callback which includes `setState` to test if this is the case.

Create

```
  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log("Fetch One Unmounted");
  }
```

Then see if the `setState` is called after the message appears.

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.setState({ isLoading: true })
   fetch(API)
  .then(response =>{
   if(response.ok){
     return response.json()
    }else{
        throw Error('Somethig went wrong...')
         }
     } )
  .then( data => this.setState({
      hits: data.hits,
      isLoading: false,
  }, () => {console.log("setState Called")}))
  .catch(error => this.setState({
       error,
       isLoading: false
      }))
  }
```

Comment: I did as you said and it shows "Fetch One Unmounted" in my testing result. What that mean? What should I do next? Thanks!!!

Comment: Sure, then you need to include a `console.log` where you make a `setState` see my updated answer.

Comment: Yes,  "setState Called" appears in my terminal.

Comment: So, does it appear after the unmount or before?

Comment: "Fetch One Unmounted" appears in my testing terminal but it doesn't appear in my console. "setState Called" appears in my console but not in my testing terminal. Is that make sense?

Comment: What is your setup?

Comment: What do you your mean the setup? Please let me know, I'm pretty new about React. Thanks!

Comment: Are you not able to see console messages?

Comment: At the moment in my console message is 
"The development server has disconnected.
Refresh the page if necessary.
setState Called    "